# Why isn't my custom setter invoked when I create a typed array of objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

http://plnkr.co/edit/TNdkfmoCc9JA1G7cEk26?p=preview

I've created a class, `Item`, which has custom `get date(): Date` and `set date(date: Date)` methods:

```
export class Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  _date: Date;

  get date(): Date {
    return this._date;
  }

  set date(date: Date) {
    this._date = date;
    this.name = (this.name + ' (updated)');
  }
}
```

In my app component, I try three things to invoke my custom setter. I thought they would all work, but only one does, and I'd like some help to understand why!

1. Pass an array of objects matching the `Item` class definition to the field typed as `Item[]`.
2. I manually set `date` on one the objects (an `Item`) in the `items` property. The date is set, but not via my setter. (Indicated by the `name` property remaining unchanged.)
3. I instantiate my own `Item`, set the `date`, and push it to `items`. This method works!

I tried being a more specific by moving properties to a constructor, guessing that maybe the object's contents were passed there when I give a typed field my array of objects. ([I made a fork of my plunker with this attempt.](http://plnkr.co/edit/PER38ZIR4r44QqNYyUdm?p=preview))

Why isn't my setter invoked when I create an array of objects bearing the class with that method?

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {Item} from './item'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{name}}</h2>
      <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{ item.name }} &mdash; {{ item.date | date:"d/M/y h:mm a" }}
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App implements OnInit {

  items: Item[];

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Understanding Getters/Setters in Typescript'
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items =  [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Item 1',
      date: new Date()
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Item 2',
      date: new Date(2016, 0, 2, 21)
    }];

    // Doesn't trigger the setter
    this.items[1].date = new Date(1985, 0);

    let testItem = new Item();
    testItem.name = 'Item 3';
    // Triggers the setter
    testItem.date = new Date(2001, 0, 1, 6);

    this.items.push(testItem);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an array/object literal:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Item 1',
  date: new Date()
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Item 2',
  date: new Date(2016, 0, 2, 21)
}];
```

It's going to overwrite the `Item[]` array you initialized `items` with in the declaration. Each of those array elements is just a plain object, not an instance of your `Item` class. For that you would need to use `new Item()`:

```
this.items = [ new Item(), new Item() ];
this.items[1].date = new Date(1985, 0);
```

As for this:

```
let testItem = new Item();
testItem.name = 'Item 3';
// Triggers the setter
testItem.date = new Date(2001, 0, 1, 6);
```

It works because you are creating a new instance of your class. And thus `testItem.date` will be your setter